What is this biplane I saw in Lučenec, Slovakia on September 17, 2024?
I took this photograph on September 17, 2024 at around 6 PM local time (4 PM UTC) in Lučenec, Slovakia. The aircraft flew no more than a couple hundred meters above ground.
 
I can't check it on Flightradar24 as the free account doesn't allow me to go back more than 7 days. If the data is not available on Flightradar24, can you at least guess what type of aircraft it is and what it may have been doing there at that time?

I looked on both ADSBexchange and FR24 and I did not see any low-lying aircraft around that area from 1530-1630Z on 9/17. Probably the tracking sites do not have ADS-B feeders in that area. Or possibly the aircraft did not have ADS-B.

Given the image quality, it's fairly likely it's an Antonov An-2.
Judging by the trees, light poles and church tower, I'd guess this is eastern Europe(ish) making it even more likely that this is an An-2. The only reason I'd doubt it was an An-2 would be because the fixed landing gear is not visible, but I think it just blends in with the lower shadow.
Edit: Missed the location given in the post - Lučenec, Slovakia
Edit 2: There's a privately-owned An-2 (Reg. OM-SON) at Prievidza, Slovakia, roughly 90km away, which is well within an An-2's range. The colors also seem to match...

https://www.airplane-pictures.net/photo/1575339/om-son-private-antonov-an-2/

Nice job finding OM-SON. That does look like an excellent candidate.

An-2 is caled "Andula" in Czech.

In the enlarged crop of the original photo, you can see one of the wheels below the lower wing. +1
